# Getting issue in Xcode 7.2 editor for 3D models

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scenekit

I have modeled an animation in Blender and I want to export it in my SceneKit project but whenever I click on my 3d file to open it in Xcode editor it's not opened, only side bar window options seems, but the 3d model doesn't, it seems blank.

Please tell what's wrong with my Xcode editor.

The files (.dae and .scn) extention are not opening. I am using Xcode 7.2 in OS X El Capitan 10.11.3.

[image]

Comment: Please, show us your file. We cannot help you without a way to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possibly a problem with your exported DAE, not Xcode. Exporting from Blender is fiddly. What happens if you open the DAE with Preview?

See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14584/properly-export-collada-for-use-in-scenekit, and also the animation export tutorial at http://trac.wildfiregames.com/wiki/AnimationExportTutorial, which is linked from  [How can I export DAE files for use in Scene Kit without seeing "untitled-animations"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539607/how-can-i-export-dae-files-for-use-in-scene-kit-without-seeing-untitled-animati).

One other thing to try: select (single click) your DAE file in Xcode. Then from the Edit menubar item, choose "Convert to SceneKit SCN file format". If that fails, your file has something in it that Xcode can't figure out.

Is your file format Collada 1.4.x, or 1.5? Check the first few lines of the DAE file (it's XML). Per [What are the requirements for supporting Collada/DAE models in SceneKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700821/what-are-the-requirements-for-supporting-collada-dae-models-in-scenekit/33702772#33702772), version 1.5 is not supported.